# Python flask error code 400, message Bad request version

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

The code of the website

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/<name>")
def user(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"


@app.route("/")
def home():
return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/admin")
def admin():
    return redirect(url_for("home"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If I go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` there are not issues but when I go to `https://127.0.0.1:5000/` (https not http this time) I get the following error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2019 17:43:25] code 400, message Bad request version ('y\x03Ðã\x80¨R¾3\x8eÜ½\x90Ïñ\x95®¢Ò\x97\x90<Ù¦\x00$\x13\x01\x13\x03\x13\x02À+À/Ì©Ì¨À,À0À')
```

The error `code 400, message Bad request version` is basically what I expected since I have not set up SSL nor have I declared what the website should do when getting a https request. What I am curious to find out is what the weird symbols mean (y\x03Ð.... and so on). This goes out to multiple questions such as: Where do they come from? Have the python code attempted to access a random memory location with no specific data? Is the data just in a format that the console cannot handle? What does it mean? You get the idea.

Comment: At a guess, the data is what the browser sends as the start of an https message.  The server tries to interpret it as an http GET, cannot, and returns 400 Bad Request and the bad request data.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the `ssl_context` in `app.run()` which configures Flask to run with HTTPS support.

See the [this article about it](https://zhangtemplar.github.io/flask/)

If this is just for testing, you can use `adhoc` mode.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc")
```